# Gradient flow through torch.nn.Parameter()

Tags: pytorch

I have a toy example

```
a = torch.ones(10)
b = torch.nn.Parameter(a,requires_grad=True)
c = (b**2).sum()
c.backward()
print(b.grad)
print(a.grad)
```

`b.grad` calculated successfully, but `a.grad` is `None`. How to make gradient flow through torch.nn.Parameter? This example looks artificial, but I work with class A derived from nn.Module and it's parameters initialized with outputs from some other Module B, and I whant to make gradients flow through A parameters to B parameters.

Comment: Gradients flow to the parameters, not any further. You need to make `a` to `require_grad=True`.

Answer (score 0):

@a_guest answer is wrong. Using `requires_grad=True` here will change nothing since `torch.nn.Parameter` is not tracked in computation graph. You should do it the other way around, to create a Parameter tensor, and then to extract a raw tensor reference out of it:

:

```
a = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones((10,)), requires_grad=True) 
b = a[:] # silly hack to convert in a raw tensor including the computation graph
b.retain_grad() # Otherwise backward pass will not store the gradient since it is not a leaf 

c = (b**2).sum() 

c.backward() 
print(b.grad) 
print(a.grad)
```

Another approach would be to copy manually the content of tensor `a` in `b`
You could fix this by making the copy explicit:

```
a = torch.ones((10,), requires_grad=True) 
b = torch.nn.Parameter(a.clone(), requires_grad=True) 

b = a
c = (b**2).sum() 

c.backward() 
print(b.grad) 
print(a.grad)
```

Yet it is not very convenient since the copy must be done systematically.